# Create multiple beans from one method in @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I am Spring for DI and am **NOT** using XML.

Based on configuration (eg. an xml/properties file), I am looking to create a number of beans (exact number is determined by the configuration) of a specific type to put in my context so that they can be autowired into classes.

I would autowire by: `@Autowired public MyClass(List<MyType> types)`

I am looking at using an class annotated with `@Configuration`.

So I can do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public MyConfigurationClass {

    @Autowired
    public void configure(ApplicationContext context) {
        // register stuff here
    }
}
```

...but it doesn't "feel" right...

What is the "Spring" way to achieve this?

EDIT:

Imagine this code, where `To` and `Ty` are just empty class definitions.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Collection<Ty> tyList() {
        return new ArrayList<Ty>() {{
            this.add(new Ty()); // could be any number of Ty instances.
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public To to(Collection<Ty> tylist) {
        return new To();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "get a variable number of class instances into a spring context"?

Comment: @Dodge - does my edit make more sense to you?

Comment: Why not create multiple `@Bean` methods?

Comment: @Cheetah if i understand your intention correctly look at my answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - see edit...I didn't make it clear that the bean count is directly linked to whats in the configuration. I dont know the bean count at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to have separate qualifiers and can Autowire as List you can do this in Spring 4:

```
@Configuration
public MyConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    public List<MyType> configure() {
        //create your dynamical list here
    }
}
```

But for Spring 3 (where generics were ignored) you would be safer to use:

```
@Configuration
public MyConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mylist")
    public List<MyType> configure() {
        //create your dynamical list here
    }
}
```

and autowire:

```
@Autowired public MyClass(@Qualifier("mylist") List<MyType> types)
```

With this you wouldn't need to touch ApplicationContext instance directly. It's not considered as very good practice.

EDIT:

Did you try this?:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("tylist")
    public Collection<Ty> tyList() {
        return new ArrayList<Ty>() {{
            this.add(new Ty()); // could be any number of Ty instances.
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public To to(@Qualifier("tylist") Collection<Ty> tylist) {
        return new To();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I swear I tried your first example - let me try again.

Comment: can you post class with this autowiring: "I would autowire by: @Autowired public MyClass(List<MyType> types)"

Comment: That is all fine. There are specified two beans: on of type "Collection<Ty>" and second of type "To". In addition, Spring should inject bean of type "Collection<Ty>" into to() method. What is the problem?

Comment: Spring is moaning that there aren't any `Ty` objects to autowire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64510/discussion-between-cheetah-and-lkrnac).

Comment: maybe this answers OP situation specifically, but this doesn't answer the title of the question. If you return a list, where and how are bean names of the items inside configured, for example?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, sorry don't understand your comment at all. Can you re-phrase it?

Comment: @luboskrnac beans have properties, not least of which are name (which can be used with qualifier) and scope. From your answer, it's unclear how items inside the returned list can be assigned name and scope in the ways that spring context would automatically pick up and wire accordingly in other parts of the application

Comment: ie, what you have here is list *as* a bean of some java items, instead of list *of* beans

Comment: List of beans where each list item is named with qualifier? WAT? I work 15 years with Spring and never even consider such beast. I smell here gaps in Spring IoC concepts.

Comment: @luboskrnac if you don't understand how beans have names, then you are the one with gaps in spring ioc concepts

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, I am aware of that standalone bean can have and by default has qualifier. Also list of beans can have qualifier. But configure list of beans in one method where each list item bean has qualifier, sorry I didn't see such stuff before. If you believe it is possible, you can create answer. I see you created some answer, but same cryptic as your comments. Maybe that is because nobody found it useful.

Comment: @luboskrnac I don't believe this is possible in general case, which is why I stated "you're out of luck" in my answer. My answer is about workaround, but I directly state so and don't pretend that it answers original question.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, yeah my "pretended" answer is much more useful to people than your "to the point" answer. +1, nice job.

Comment: @luboskrnac your pretended answer is useless to people who were looking for something quite specific. A more common question on how to create a bean of collection type has been asked and answered many times elsewhere

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, conversation with you is useless!

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on where and how properties are read. If you read those properties using vanilla java, you could register bean definitions by implementing BeanFactoryPostProcessor. However, if the properties themselves come as a bean (eg. as a result of @ConfigurationProperties), I'm somewhat confident you're out of luck. After googling for some time, I come to conclusion that the only robust solution is to refactor whole design, and instead of providing multiple MyType beans, provide single MyTypeProvider bean, which in turn would have a single method with signature `List<MyType> getStuff()`. Then, at the point where you had `List<MyType>` injected, inject `List<MyTypeProvider>` instead, and merge their results of `getStuff` into a single `List<MyType>`. Again, I know this is more of a workaround, but this the best I could find so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but I *believe* this is what you want.

```
public interface MyStuff {
  void doSomething();
}

@Scope("prototype") // 1
@Service("stuffA") // 2
public class MyStuffImpl_A implements MyStuff {
  public void doSomething()
  {
     // do your stuff
  }
}

@Scope("prototype")
@Service("stuffB")
public class MyStuffImpl_B implements MyStuff {
  public void doSomething()
  {
     // do your stuff the B way ;)
  }
}
```

now you can do:

```
public class UseTheStuff {

  @Autowired
  private Provider<MyStuff> stuffA; // 3

  @Autowired
  private Provider<MyStuff> stuffB;  // 4

  public void doStuffWithTheProvider(){
    MyStuff stuffA.get(); // 5
    MyStuff stuffB.get(); // 6
  }
}
```

1. tell spring to use this implementation as prototype
2. name this implementatnion of MyStuff: "stuffA"
3. get a Provider (the name "stuffA" tells spring to inject a MyStuffImpl_A provider)
4. get a Provider (the name "stuffB" tells spring to inject a MyStuffImpl_B provider)
5. use the provider to create an instance of MyStuffImpl_A
6. use the provider to create an instance of MyStuffImpl_B

Comment: I think, It doesn't look what OP is asking for. He wants create beans programically by specifying number of creation how many beans should be created after application context instantiation. Moreover, he wants to use @Configuration annotation which indicates that spring must keep marked class as beans blue print class (similar like xml file)

Comment: @energizer possible. as mentioned, i was not sure if that is what he wanted to do. at least it was a try to help :-)